# Как сделать притяжение игрока к стене (Composite collider)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю 2D игру, в которой персонаж выполнен в виде треугольника. Он "летает" по сцене с помощью выстрелов. Идея в том что когда он "подлетает" к стенке, можно нажать на кнопку, притянуться и зафиксироваться на стенке или любом другом препятствии. Сама карта сделана с помощью `CompositeCollider2d`, а персонаж имеет `OverlapCircle` для распознавания столкновений.

[image: Принтскрин сцены]

```
isTouchingObstacle = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(obstacleCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsObstacle);
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу понять какой алгоритм надо использовать. Я пытался решить этот вопрос так:

1. Добавил к каждой стенке `AreaEffector2D` и при столкновении изменял значение с 0 до 10, но это крайне неудобно, так как уровне много, а код один. В каждом уровне разное количество стенок, следовательно и `AreaEffetor2D`

```
forceArea1.forceMagnitude = 10f;
forceArea2.forceMagnitude = 10f;
forceArea3.forceMagnitude = 10f;
```

2. Я использовал функцию `Lerp` дабы плавно изменять положение игрока. Для этого я считывал угол поворота игрока и определял куда нужно его притянуть, но это создает баги. Ведь если игрок смотрит вправо, то он не обязательно должен притянуться влево

```
if (obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 45f || obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 325f){
   transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(this.transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - .2f), 1f);
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
}
else if (obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 45f && obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 135f){
   transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(this.transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x + .2f, transform.position.y), 1f);
}
else if(obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 135f && obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 225f){
   transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(this.transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + .2f), 1f);
}
else if(obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 225f && obstacleCheck.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 325f){
   transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(this.transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x - .2f, transform.position.y), 1f);
}
```

Comment: Как вы пытались решить эту проблему? В чем вопрос? Вы не можете физику притягивания придумать или код написать? Если первое, напишите как можно больше подробностей об этом и ваших попытках, если второе, покажите неработающий код. А пока вопрос выглядит как "я пишу игру, мне нужна фича, напишите мне пожалуйста код".

Comment: Проблема пожалуй больше в самой физике. Я пытался решить этот вопрос так:
1) Добавил к каждой стенке AreaEffector2D и при столкновении изменял значение с 0 до 10, но это крайне неудобно, так как уровне много, а код один. В каждом уровне разное количество стенок, следовательно и AreaEffetor2D
2) Я использовал функцию Lerp дабы плавно изменять положение игрока. Для этого я считывал угол поворота игрока и определял куда нужно его притянуть, но это создает баги. Ведь если игрок смотрит вправо, то он не обязательно должен притянуться влево

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю как добавить код к сообщению, так что вставлю его в сам вопрос

Comment: Добавил код, надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Я добавил ссылку на то как выглядит сцена, надеюсь это вам поможет

Comment: Обращаться к собеседнику вот так: @Ranvus. И я вам не помогу, потому что в юнити не шарю, я всего-лишь помог оформить вопрос.

Comment: @aepot, хорошо спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить по горизонтальной оси `AddForce` к `Rigidbody2D` вашего персонажа. Пример использования можно посмотреть [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html).

Если в вашей игре есть гравитация, то можно добавить `AddForce` и к вертикально оси, чтобы скомпенсировать притяжение игрока...